# Free all surfaces in SDL?

Tags: c++

So I have a bunch of `SDL_Surface*`'s in a C++ program. I want the program to free all `SDL_Surface*`'s when the program closes by default but I can't find a function to do it. I'm currently using an array (`SDL_Surface* imgDict[64];` ) to store all of them and then cycling through them and calling `SDL_FreeSurface()` on each one of them which seems to work. Am I doing this right/am I doing anything wrong and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You'll probably get a better reception on Stack Overflow, as it is more suited to implementation questions such as this one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Last time I asked a software development question on there I was told that those types of questions go here :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey oh....oops xD Is there a way I can "migrate" this question over to there then? Or do I have to delete this question and ask the question again over there?

Comment: Are you familiar with [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)? If not, you might want to get acquainted and possibly edit your question.

Comment: You've created surfaces for some purpose; if you use them (e.g. blit, etc.) - you already have other pointers to surface. If you don't - then why they still alive? While your approach is somewhat correct, it doesn't looks like a very good idea to keep array of surfaces for the sole purpose of deleting them. Depending on your overall software design there may be better options, like notifying other subsystems to cleanup their part of data.